# for loop else including those matched item

Tags: java

Transaction list:

```
Product code |Product Type |Product Name
0001         |Food         |Chocolate
0002         |Consumer     |Pen
0003         |Consumer     |Earphone
```

Discount list:

```
Product Type|Discount
Food        |70%
Industry    |50%
```

I want the loop through product list and calculate discount and find out which has no discount

```
for (Transactionlist tx: txs) {
   for (Discountlsit disc: discs) {
     if (tx.getProduct.equal(disc.getProduct()) {
       // calculate discount
     } else {
       // how to find not found, because even the matched one happen in else? 
     }
   }
}
```

Result I want from the `else` is the not found discount:

```
Product code |Product Type |Product Name
0002         |Consumer     |Pen
0003         |Consumer     |Earphone
```

Comment: Are you fetching these lists from some db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag for whether you found a discount when you iterated through the discount list. Then, afterwards, you handle the case where you didn't find a discount.

```
for (TransactionList tx : txs) {
    boolean foundDiscount = false;
    for (DiscountList discount : discountList) {
      if (tx.getProduct().equals(discount.getProduct()) {
          foundDiscount = true;
          // TODO: calculate discount
      }
    }
    if (!foundDiscount) {
        // TODO: Handle when no discount is found
    }
 }
```